# Null Character in Text Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> file = open('foo.txt')
>>> file.seek(2)  
2  
>>> file.read(1)  
'\n'  
>>> file.tell()  
4
```

why didn't the current position move 1 character forward? Isn't `'\n'` supposed to be 1 character?

Content of the first 4 lines of the file:

> 1@
>   2@
>   3@
>   @

PS : I'm on windows.

Comment: You put the cursor on the second position, read the character on the third and it moved forward and now it's on the forth position. No?

Comment: NO! for any other character it moves one position forward!

Comment: Please post the content of the file.

Comment: content of the file is irrelevant! the only thing that matters is that I use the file.read(1) to move one character but it moves 2 position forward, the content is <1@\n2@\n3@\n....> if it helps in anyway.

Comment: are you on windows, by any chance?

Comment: Please post the content of the file in your question exactly the way it is, are you printing `\n` as the two chars **\, n** or are you simply clicking `Enter` to get a linebreak ?

Comment: I just ran your code and file.tell( ) returned 3.  Are you using 16-bit character encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to interpret the value of [`file.tell()` for a text file](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell) -- it is just some opaque number representing the position in the stream (you can pass it to `file.seek()`).

In a text file, `file.read(1)` reads one Unicode character (codepoint), not byte. Depending on the character encoding used to read the text file, one Unicode codepoint could be from one to four bytes (usually).

The default is universal newlines mode: `'\r\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\n'` are all translated to just `'\n'`.

To see the file content as bytes, open in binary mode: `'rb'`. `file.tell()` return position in bytes in this case.

`b'\0'` (null byte) indicates utf-16 encoding that is common on Windows.